# Cut every .mp4 in folder by half with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, loops, ffmpeg

I have a folder with ~200 mp4-files and I need to cut the last half of every one of them. So if a video is 140 seconds I need to cut out the last 70 seconds so that the resulting output is the preceding 70 seconds.

I would assume the loop would look a bit like this:

```
for i in *.mp4; do
    let A=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $i)
    let A=${A%.*}
    let A=$A/2
    ffmpeg -sseof $A -i $i ${i%.mp4}
done
```

But I get "syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".246848")" from the first 'let'. This corresponds to the float of the video duration.
For all I know there could be many other mistakes with my loop

Also some files have spaces and special characters if that matters.

Comment: Try pasting your code into shellcheck.net to get an analysis of the issues.

Comment: With the exception of needing to use double quotes on the last two $ : 
ffmpeg -sseof $A -i "$i" "${i%.mp4}"
and that it is preferable to use '(( A ))' instead of 'let A', I got no error..

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like so:

```
for f in *.mp4; do
  dur=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 "$f")
  dur=$((${dur%.*} / 2))
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -t $dur -c copy "${f%.*}_half.mp4"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Only thing is that I had to remove -c copy, because the video stutters at the beginning with it enabled